# Instagram how to know if my app is Live

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an app on Instagram which was created before Nov 17 2015.

After Instagram Platform and documentation update, I re-approved all the permissions I needed through the review process.

It say in the [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) that I could switch to Live mode by clicking a button in my app configuration.

I don't see any button there.

Is there a chance that apps which was created before the changes will see the button only in after the grace period of June 2016?

Can I assume my app is Live?

Comment: Same issue here - did you find an answer?  I've got approval but don't see a button.

Comment: Not really.. Unfortunately

Comment: Hopefully everything continues working after June 1

Answer (score 0):

There is no button. Switch should be automatic